# ko.toJSON & JavaScriptSerializer issue

Tags: c#, knockout.js, javascriptserializer

I am using asp.net web form and a hidden value to store my knockout viewmodel to pass to next page after serialization.

`ko.toJSON(viewModel)` returns `[{}]` in case if viewmodel has no element in it. 
When this is passed to javascript serializer it blows up because string has "null" as string.

```
var stringValue = MyHiddenField.Value

var listOfObjects = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<MyObjects>>(stringValue);
```

Is there any way to handle empty JSON by JavascriptSerializer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because you are initializing your observables like this:

```
var a = ko.observable();
```

If you do this, the unwrapped value of `a` will be undefined. ko.toJSON calls the native JSON.stringify function, which will not serialize properties with undefined values. To prevent this, the easiest way is to initialize your observables like this:

```
var a = ko.observable(null);
```

On serialization, this will result in "a":null, which the JavaScriptSerializer should be able to digest.

Here is a fiddle with examples, check console : http://jsfiddle.net/v87Ky/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This has given me the resolution to my problem. :)